# Two styles for setting defaults

Tags: javascript

I have seen two different "styles" for setting a default value `default` to the variable `argument` in JavaScript:

```
argument = argument || default     // Version 1
argument || (argument = default)   // Version 2
```

Are these completely equivalent? Is one faster than the other, or better in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one avoids any assignment whatsoever if `argument` is already truthy, so it may theoretically be a smidge faster.

Really though I doubt you'd ever see a difference.

---

Just to break it down a bit more

1. Assign `argument` to itself if `argument` is already truthy, otherwise assign `argument` to `default`
2. Evaluate the boolean condition `argument || (argument = default)`.  If `argument` is already truthy, the evaluation will **short circuit**, and nothing else will happen.  If `argument` is not truthy, the second half of the boolean condition will hit, and `argument` will be assigned `default`